# Why are some testthat tests on R-devel much slower than on R 4.1.2

Tags: r, testthat, r-devel

Trying to figure out why mkin 1.1.0 (to be released) tests fail on winbuilder and r-hub with R-devel, I am checking locally with R-devel on Linux. I am finding that certain tests run reasonably quick when using R 4.1.2

```
me@computer:~/git/mkin (main)$ time Rscript -e "testthat::test_file('tests/testthat/test_tests.R', reporter = 'Progress')"
Loading required package: mkin
Loading required package: parallel
✔ | F W S  OK | Context
✔ |         9 | Hypothesis tests [9.0s]                                                                                                                                                                                               

══ Results ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Duration: 9.0 s

[ FAIL 0 | WARN 0 | SKIP 0 | PASS 9 ]

real    1m48,779s
user    4m37,386s
sys     3m17,240s
```

The additional time reported by the unix time command is spent in the `setup_script.R` file.

When I use locally compiled R-devel, the same tests need more than four times as much time

```
Loading required package: mkin
Loading required package: parallel
✔ | F W S  OK | Context
✔ |         9 | Hypothesis tests [42.4s]                                                                                                                                                                                              

══ Results ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Duration: 42.4 s

[ FAIL 0 | WARN 0 | SKIP 0 | PASS 9 ]

real    2m21,823s
user    5m7,507s
sys     3m14,287s
```

In both cases, R uses openblas-pthread, see for R 4.1.2:

```
me@computer:~/git/mkin (main)$ Rscript -e "sessionInfo()"
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.13.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.2
```

and for R-devel:

```
me@computer:~/git/mkin (main)$ Rscript-devel -e "sessionInfo()"
R Under development (unstable) (2022-03-02 r81842)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.13.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.0
```

You can try to reproduce this from my latest commit (increase cloning depth if necessary)

```
git clone git@github.com:jranke/mkin --depth=10
cd mkin
git checkout 77c248ca40b82ec00a756cd82f12968131f78959
```

Stripping down the setup script to what's really needed to run the tests from this particular file reduces the time difference:

```
$ git pull origin stackoverflow_71340826
$ Rscript -e "testthat::test_file('tests/testthat/test_tests.R', reporter = 'Progress')"
Loading required package: mkin
Loading required package: parallel
✔ | F W S  OK | Context
✔ |         9 | Hypothesis tests [7.8s]                                                                                                                                                                                               

══ Results ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Duration: 7.8 s

[ FAIL 0 | WARN 0 | SKIP 0 | PASS 9 ]
```

as compared to

```
$ Rscript-devel -e "testthat::test_file('tests/testthat/test_tests.R', reporter = 'Progress')"
Loading required package: mkin
Loading required package: parallel
✔ | F W S  OK | Context
✔ |         9 | Hypothesis tests [13.9s]                                                                                                                                                                                              

══ Results ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Duration: 14.0 s

[ FAIL 0 | WARN 0 | SKIP 0 | PASS 9 ]
```

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by some bug fixes in the DLL info interface in R, which resulted in slower execution of the many calls to `getLoadedDLLs()` in my mkin code for compiled models. Thanks to a [suggestion by Thomas Kalibera on r-pkg-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2022q3/008252.html) I could reduce these calls to the necessary minimum, so the problem went away in mkin v1.1.1.